# Index issue through List containing equal values in python

Tags: python, list, keras, svm

I have two lists called `predicted_labels_ssup0` and `predicted_labels_ssup1` which contain the probabilities of SVM predictions of each instance. Some how, a number of probability values are perfectly equal. And my goal is to extract the indexes of the most high probability values and save it in another list called `confident_inst_indexes`.

So here is how I did:

```
confident_inst_indexes=[]
for x,y in zip(predicted_labels_ssup0,predicted_labels_ssup1):


    if (x > 0.997):
        #print('x',x)

        #print(predicted_labels_ssup0.tolist().index(x))
        confident_inst_indexes= np.append(confident_inst_indexes,predicted_labels_ssup0.tolist().index(x))
    elif (y > 0.995):
        #print('y',y)
        #print(predicted_labels_ssup1.tolist().index(y))
        confident_inst_indexes= np.append(confident_inst_indexes,predicted_labels_ssup1.tolist().index(y))
```

The problem here, is that the probability values that are equal and satisfy the fixed condition got always the same index of the list which is the index of the first occupation of that value.

How can I fix this ? Any propositions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you are trying to do, you can use argwhere from numpy library directly. It returns all index where a condition is met

```
a = np.argwhere(predicted_labels_ssup0 > 0.997)
b = np.argwhere(predicted_labels_ssup1 > 0.995)
confident_inst_indexes = [a, b] # you may have to flatten too
```

I hope it helps,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use enumerate while iterating to get the index:

```
a = [1,5,3,5]
b = [0,2,0,4]
for index, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    print(index, x, y)
```

You seem to search the index from a numpy thingy with `tolist().index(x)`, this will give you always the first match of x. Maybe this is the reason you get always the same index.